# Springboot hot-reload is not working in IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have two project, project A is a springboot project, I build it as jar and imported it in project B, the POM like below

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.tony</groupId>
     <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

in the project B, some class extend the class from project A, it's work fine but the hot reload is not working in project B, after change the code of project B, I can see the springboot rebooted and reload in the console, but the new code is not take effect (change thymeleaf code is reload fine), and if I run the project B in debug mode, everything is fine. also if I create the project B as a module of project A, everything is fine too, I don't know what happen and how to resolve it, seems all the configuration is correct,  below is the POM of project A for your reference, thank you a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tony</groupId>
<artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>framework</name>
<description>bztech spring framework</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions><!-- 去掉springboot默认配置 -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- 引入log4j2依赖 -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!--页面模板依赖-->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.62</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
        <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tony</groupId>
        <artifactId>jodconvert</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: I do not understand your workflow. Do you run project B using jar from project A, then modify jar from project A and expect the changes to appear without reloading application running in project B? I do not think this is something you can do.

Comment: I mean run project B using jar from project A, and modify project B code hope the project B reload automatically. I just change the project B . the project A has already build as a jar, the jar include all the spring-boot dependencies, thanks you.